# Dictionary update method. Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Want to know why that function doesn't work ?

```
students = {'dsd': 13}

student1 = {'dsdsd': 15}

print(students.update(student1))
```

After printing it just brings out `None` in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update` method merges the `dict`s in-place and returns 'None', which is what you're printing. You need to print `students` itself.

```
students = {'dsd': 13}
student1 = {'dsdsd': 15}
students.update(student1)
print(students)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `dict1.update(dict2)` update the value of `dict1` with the values of `dict2` but do not returns anything (hence printing `None` in your case). In order to see the updated values, you need to do:

```
students.update(student1)
print(students)
```

As a reference, check [`dict.update()` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) which says:

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.